# /DIR="D:\XXX\YYY" is not working in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

When I pass command line parameter to an exe as **/DIR="D:\XXX\YYY"**, the files get extracted on **C:\XXX\YYY** the drive alone gets changed at the time of **/SILENT** installation. Given *usepreviousappdir=no* but it doesn't work.

Don't know why it is happening. Anybody knows solution for this na`enter code here`.., plz let me know

Comment: Show us a log file documenting the problem.

Comment: In the my question there is the answer at the your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908769/setup-command-line-parameters-dir-x-dirname-not-working